# Power Query Text String to Duration in Minutes (1h 30m) to (90)

Tags: powerquery

I have a spreadsheet with various time stamps formatted with text ex. "1h 30m", is there a way to transform this to duration in minutes in Power Query?

[Spreadsheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuw6H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= Expression.Evaluate(Text.Trim(Text.Replace("1h 30m","h","*60+"),"m"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; however, I need a formula that will work with an entire column that has many different values some with hour and minute values "1h 30m" "1h 2m" etc. and some only minutes 15m 10m etc. So the formula would need to take the value in each row remove the text (h and m) and convert it into minutes.

Comment: Add a custom column,then input this formula.
The full code is:
= Table.AddColumn(YourTableName, "minutes", each Expression.Evaluate(Text.Trim(Text.Replace([YourColumnName],"h","*60+"),"m")))

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and I appreciate your help... So I put in the formula above, changed the table name and column name and it gives me a column with "error" =Table.AddColumn(Table1, "minutes", each Expression.Evaluate(Text.Trim(Text.Replace([Pend],"h","*60+"),"m")))

Comment: This is the error it gives me when I click into it: Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation

Comment: YourTableName is the name of last step，not the name of query.

Comment: Your can click 'Add Custom Column' button,only input = Expression.Evaluate(Text.Trim(Text.Replace([Pend],"h","*60+"),"m"))